# wp_oembed_get( $url, $args = '' ) issue

Tags: wordpress

`wp_oembed_get( $url, $args = '' )` works great for the external hosted videos, but for locally hosted videos it does not work. It returns nothing if we put the local video url. It works perfect when using *youtube* and *vimeo* videos. I needed this to show the video outside the content.

Answer (score 1):

check the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_oembed_get)

**Return Value**

If `$url` is a valid url to a supported provider, the function returns the embed code provided to it from the oEmbed protocol. Otherwise, it will return false.

`$url` is only work with the supported providers like **youtube,vimeo**

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But as there is html5 video player in WP-3.6, I thought local URL should also work but it does not.

Comment: ok cool it may avail in the next version of WP, upvote and tick it my answer if my answer is right